# Installing ubutu 14.04 on Windows 64 - gettting Windows Disk Image Burner pop-up -file too big to put on CD

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I downloaded the `ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso` file to my Windows 7 disk drive and tried to open it. I then get a Windows Disk Image Burner pop-up.

When I try to proceed, it errors out saying the file is too big for a CD.
How do I get past this?

Comment: Either use a DVD or a 4GB USB the instructions for creating a Live USB are in the [Ubuntu web page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu).

Comment: Also if you only have a CD, you can get a CD image for 12.04.5 LTS (supported till 2017) here http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/

Answer (score 1):

As the iso image is too big for a CD insert a DVD.

Answer (score 1):

You can write to a DVD as [cl-netbox](https://askubuntu.com/users/260935/cl-netbox) said in [his answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/667818/344926).

On the other hand, *if your machine doesn't have a DVD writer:*

1. [use a USB stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

   **or**
2. download the [minimal install 64-bit](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso) and burn that to a CD.

   The minimal install will however download everything it needs from the Internet, so it will be much slower to install though...

<sub>[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)</sub>

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**